# Limit for inductances

Tags: transformer

In the circuit below :[image]

It is possible in physics to have :

L1 = 1 H
L2 = 2H
L3 = 1 H

and couple inductances like that:

K1 LL1 LL2 1.414
K2 LL2 LL3 1.414

I think I must respect K < sqrt(LxLy), true ?

For L2, I think it's necessary to have 2 times than L1 or L3, true ?

I don't understand why LSpice simulation software give me the error "bad K coupling for inductances" even K is < 1.

Good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my spice simulator you can't have k values greater than unity.

Comment: ok, so if I put K1 = K2 = 0.9 and L1 = L3 = 0.7 and L2 = 1.4 is it possible ? LSpice said bad parameters not Multisim